# How can I convert the number of DSP48/BRAM to the number of LUTs and FFs in FGPA

Tags: fpga, vhdl

I have a trouble with estimation of logic utilization.

I am Ph.D student who research the efficient implementation of signal processing algorithms. So, I have to compare the logic utilization of proposed method with conventional method.

Therefore, the comparison of gate counts for each methods is the best way to evaluate efficiency of logic utilization.
Unfortunately, as you know, the Xilinx simulator does not provide the gate counts anymore.

Instead of gate count, we can estimate the logic utilization with the number of LUTs and FFs.
So, I did not use the DSP48 and Block memory by using synthesis settings so that every logic can be implemented by LUTs and FFs.

However, although I had configured –max_dsp = 0, 
the decimation filter/FFT generated by IPs,FIR compiler/FFT, still used DSP48 and BRAM.

Here are the questions.

**1.How can I generate decimation filter without DSP48 using FIR Compiler. 
I would like to generate decimation filter only with CLBs using FIR compiler.**

**2.Is there any criteria convert the number of DSP48 to the number of LUTs and FFs?**

**3.In addition, is there any criteria convert the number of block memory to the number of LUTs or Memory LUTs?**

Comment: USE_DSP48 constrain in synthesis can infer different circuit for your purpose. Use DSP48 values are:
• auto (default)
• yes
• no
• true (XCF only)
• false (XCF only)

Comment: *Therefore, the comparison of gate counts for each methods is the best way to evaluate efficiency of logic utilization* I do **not** concur. You're demonstrating that yourself: In reality, FPGAs have DSP slices, and for good reasons. You're arbitrarily claiming LUTs are the right measure. So I'll go ahead and arbitrarily claim that DSP slices are the right measure, just to make my point!

Comment: Also, Xilinx tools don't show gate count anymore, *because there's no gates in a modern FPGA*. Simple as that. It's all LUTs. So, gate count simply doesn't exist, and that's another indication that it's a bad measure.

Answer (score 2):

> How can I generate decimation filter without DSP48 using FIR Compiler. I would like to generate decimation filter only with CLBs using FIR compiler.

Configure your FIR IP core and/or your synthesis filters to not utilize DSP slices. There's *constrains* that allow you to configure that.

By the way, I doubt this is a sensible thing to do. You're doing DSP, so use the DSP hardware. Comparing things as if that doesn't exist is unfairly favoring the thing that doesn't use DSP slices.

> Is there any criteria convert the number of DSP48 to the number of LUTs and FFs?

Sure. Implement a multiplier in discrete logic. In fact, your synthesizer will do exactly that when you forbid it to utilize your DSP slizes.

As with **everything** in FPGAs: there's a tradeoff between speed, amount of resources used and latency. Without defining boundaries for all three, you can't tell how you should be implementing something. You can build a thousands-of-LUTs single-clock multiplier; you can build a much smaller multi-clock-cycle one, or you can build a multi-clock-cycle pipelined one. It all depends on what you define to be appropriate.

> In addition, is there any criteria convert the number of block memory to the number of LUTs or Memory LUTs?

This should be answering itself, but: I'm sure you can model a bit stored in block RAM as an FF.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely point 3 is wrong. Memory has a totally different structure from gates. in the ASIC world, where I come from, the area of a block is always split in gates-area and memory-area.

The reason is that the size of a memory is non-linear. Small memories use up a lot more area per cell then large ones. Very small memories are therefore implemented using what we call a 'register file'.

<sub>A register file is a memory comprised of real registers but due to the regular structure are in density between random registers+gates and memories.</sub>

By the way: counting LUTS does not help either. A LUT can represent a singe NAND gate or a complex group as big as many, many NAND gates. (The area of a NAND gate is used as unit for ASIC circuit area).

Last but not least: area alone is not enough.
Your new algorithm may be 'smaller' in gates but unsuitable for pipe-lining and thus can not run at high speeds. In which case it will be discarded in favor of one which can be pipe-lined or one which is easier to lay out using a datapath compiler.

Answer (score 0):

> I am Ph.D student who research the efficient implementation of signal
>   processing algorithms.

This will be an interesting topic - first you need to define "efficient".  As others have noted, you cannot really compare "area" using LUTs anymore (and that's been the case for a very long time!).

As a practising engineer, what is usually important in the real world is more likely to be "how much does it cost?" or "how much power does it consume?" etc.

> So, I have to compare the logic utilization of
>   proposed method with conventional method.

I don't think you *have* to compare logic utilisation...

Can you perhaps target a device in different ways and compare

- the "equivalent cost" (based on "how many of the block you could fit in your selected device)
- or amount of power consumed?

You 
could perhaps compare different device families this way, or even different size devices in the same family, to see where the sweet spot for cost of silicon area or power comes etc.